# Django 2 TestCase assertQuerysetEqual

Tags: django

Maybe I am misunderstanding the implementation of the `assertQuerysetEqual`, but I am trying to build a test that would verify that my `model` `meta` `ordering` is working as expected. Of all the info I found, I think this is what I should do:

models.py

```
class Name(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        "First Name",
        max_length=100,
        )
    middle_name = models.CharField(
        "Middle Name or Initial",
        max_length=100,
        default='',
        )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        "Last Name",
        max_length=200,
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name']
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Name


class NameModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setupUpTestData(cls):
        # test_name_1
        Name.objects.create(
        first_name='Anny',
        middle_name='Ann',
        last_name='Anvil',
        )
        # test_name_2
        Name.objects.create(
            first_name='Anny',
            middle_name='B',
            last_name='Anvil',
            )
        # test_name_3
        Name.objects.create(
            first_name='Banny',
            last_name='Anvil',
            )
        # test_name_4
        Name.objects.create(
            first_name='Banny',
            last_name='Banvil',
            )

    def test_meta_ordering_last_first_middle(self):
        test_name_1 = Name.objects.get(pk=1)
        test_name_2 = Name.objects.get(pk=2)
        test_name_3 = Name.objects.get(pk=3)
        test_name_4 = Name.objects.get(pk=4)

        expected_qs = list(test_name_1, test_name_2,
                        test_name_3, test_name_4
                        )

        test_qs = Name.objects.all()

        self.assertQuerysetEqual(test_qs, expected_qs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

1. The `setUpTestData` class is named incorrectly (you have `setupUpTestData`)
2. You have the wrong syntax for creating a list; it should be `[a, b, c, d]`, not `list(a, b, c, d)`, which is a `TypeError`.
3. The most important, `assertQuerysetEqual`, by default, uses `repr` to get a representation of the values in the queryset. In your case it will work if you do:

---

```
expected_qs = map(repr, [test_name_1, test_name_2, test_name_3, test_name_4])
```

You call `repr` on each object so they will match what `assertQuerysetEqual` will do.

One final note: your test would also pass if the ordering was by `id`. If I were you I'd create the objects in a different order, so you are more confident that it's the ordering by name that is being tested. Or you could get the objects by name, instead of `pk`, as a way of self-documenting the test, making the ordering obvious.

Comment: Apparently I have bigger issues. I would like to mark it as an answer, but I was reading my test error information wrong. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744472/django-2-test-created-object-cannot-be-gotten-for-tests)

Comment: The issue seems the same, actually, you're still misspelling `setUpTestData` (it's an uppercase U).