# Django 2 Test: Created object cannot be gotten for tests

Tags: django

I've read about building programs starting with tests, so I thought I'd give it a shot. I've made my initial `project` and `app` and a `model`, but when I try to run a test, I get a "Does not exist" error. I've run the migrations, is there more I have to do before I can run a test? Here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Name(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        "First Name",
        max_length=100,
        )
    middle_name = models.CharField(
        "Middle Name or Initial",
        max_length=100,
        default='',
        )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        "Last Name",
        max_length=200,
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

from contacts.models import Name


class TestNameModel(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setupTestData(cls):
        Name.objects.create(first_name='Banny', last_name='Banvil')

    def test_name_exists(self):
        name = Name.objects.get(id=1)
        print (name)
```

And the error that I get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_name_exists (contacts.tests.TestNameModel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CrazyCarl/Software/contact/contacts/tests.py", line 12, in test_name_exists
    name = Name.objects.get(id=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
contacts.models.DoesNotExist: Name matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I tried making an object in the terminal to see if it was working:

```
>>>from contacts.models import Name
>>>Name.objects.create(last_name='John', first_name='Smith')
<Name: John, Smith>
>>>Name.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Name: John, Smith>]>
>>>n = Name.objects.get(id=1)
>>>print (n)
John, Smith
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s `setUpTestData` not `setupTestData`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [fixtures](http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html). Basically you have nothing in your db when you try do get(id=1)

Also fixtures will save your time in the feature. Good luck!